# Is it possible to define SharePoint metadata in HTML tags?

Tags: html, sharepoint, search, metadata

I am using SharePoint search to crawl an external website which is made up of standard HTML files.  Seems like I am missing a lot of the functionality since the files are not stored in SharePoint itself and don't have custom meta data, columns and managed properties.

Is it possible to create tags in the HTML file to be crawled by SharePoint and used as managed properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

theoretically yes but it would require lot of customization as you have to create a i-filter which will handle request for html objects and reads your metadata tags and store it to metadata properties in search database. and then pass it to actual i-filter to process it as it was being processed.
using OOTB functionality it would not be possible

Comment: I see. I was hoping for a built in feature.  So what exactly can I do with crawling an external website? I would like to sort webpages into different categories and create an advanced search page with a dropdown.  I know this would be easy if I hosted the pages in SharePoint but I don't wish to do that.

Comment: the thing you can play around with is URL of the page which would be only managed property available to you so structure your site accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Also looking to do this, according to these [two](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/sharepoint-search-and-html-meta-tags.html) [blogs](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Daniel/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=114), this may be possible using html meta tags